# Titrations in three equibilums

Tags: acid-base, solutions, titration

You have three solutions:

- 0.1 M solution of a weak monovalent acid
- 0.1 M solution of a strong monovalent acid
- 0.1 M solution of a weak divalent acid

Each solution is titrated with 0.15 M NaOH. What will be the same for the 3 titrations?

I know the answer is:

> The volume of the NaOH solution will be the same when you reach the first equivalence point

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acid-base equilibria always exchange only one proton at a time - so if you have a diprotic acid, that's equivalent to having two monoprotic acids with different $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$.

When you titrate either of the three solutions with $\ce{NaOH}$, the first equivalence point is reached when the strongest (lowest $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$) acid reacts completely - i.e. when you have added the same amount of moles of base as moles of the strongest acid were there in the solution.

Remember that the volume of titrating solution added at the equivalence point can be calculated from the respective concentrations:

$$ V_\ce{NaOH} = V_\ce{HA} \cfrac{C_\ce{HA}}{C_\ce{NaOH}} $$

Since all three examples have the same concentration of acid, the first equivalence point will happen when the same amount of $\ce{NaOH}$ has been added to all three solutions. What will be different will be the $\mathrm{pH}$ corresponding to this equivalence point, but the amount of base added will be the same.

To illustrate this, I did a quick plot of $\mathrm{pH}$ vs. volume of $\ce{NaOH}$ solution added for three acids that fit your question: strong monoprotic hydrochloric acid ($\ce{HCl}$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} \approx -7$), weak monoprotic acetic acid ($\ce{HAc}$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 4.8$) and weak diprotic glycine ($\ce{H2Gly}$, $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a1} = 2.34$,  $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2} = 9.6$).

[image]

As you can see, although starting $\mathrm{pH}$ values are different, and although glycine goes on to have a second equivalence point, the first equivalence point (solid vertical line) occurs at the same volume of base solution.